# Chrome tabs using 100% CPU, even though they're not open

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I've noticed some strange behaviour with Chrome on OSX El Capitan recently. `Google Chrome Helper` will start using 100% CPU, and on closer inspection of the Chrome Task Manager, I see that tabs I don't even have open are thrashing the CPU.

For example, in this screenshot "Google Maps" is using 84%, but it's not open:

[image]

There are also tabs that I don't have open that appear to be sitting idle - old google searches, both of my gmail accounts, etc.

Does anybody have a clue what is going on? Does it look like I have some malware?

Comment: This does not seem to be a malware. Looking at image, it seems that you are sharing your location. Are you also using offline gmail? Try setting chrome to ask before accessing location (check settings). Also, you can logoff your google account. If you do not want to do that, turn off gmail notification and offline gmail (if using). Disable extensions, which are not in use. Deselect "Continue running background apps.." option from settings. You may also want to clear old browser history and contents. It is also recommended to update display driver (seems unrelated but helps).

Comment: Thanks for the tips Sandeep. I'm not using offline Gmail, but I'll try them all out. I'm curious what you see that shows I am sharing my location though?

Comment: Device driver could well be possible. It's a hackintosh I'm running after all :/

Comment: Chrome uses location icon in address bar to show that website is accessing your location. Google uses location when you use maps or search something (to provide result based on your location). In image, it is at left of bookmark icon at address bar. It looks like a dot within circle.